# SQL advanced sorting using ORDER BY

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

I can't figure out how to sort some of my results using the ORDER BY clause. I'm using PostgreSQL and I have a table which records actions that a user performs in my application. It records user_id, message_date, message_subject. Here is my current SQL statement for selecting from this table:

```
SELECT 
  message_subject, 
  count (message_subject) AS message_count,
  user_id,
  message_date,

FROM 
  view_app_message

WHERE
  message_date >= $P{FROM} AND message_date <= $P{TO} AND
  belongs_to IN ($P{RESTAURANT_IDS})

GROUP BY
  message_date,
  user_id,
  message_subject

ORDER BY
  message_date,
  user_id,
  message_count DESC
```

This gives me results which looks like this:

```
message_subject | message_count | user_id | message_date
   login        |       2       |    1    | 2014.04.01
   error        |       1       |    1    | 2014.04.01
   payment      |       1       |    1    | 2014.04.01
   login        |       7       |    2    | 2014.04.01
   error        |       5       |    2    | 2014.04.01
   login        |       10      |    1    | 2014.04.02
   error        |       9       |    1    | 2014.04.02
   login        |       2       |    2    | 2014.04.02
   payment      |       1       |    2    | 2014.04.02
```

What I want is to order these records by the total of all the `message_count`s for each user. For example user 1 has 4 messages from 2014.04.01 and user 2 has 12. User 2's records should be sorted descending BEFORE user 1's records like so:

```
message_subject | message_count | user_id | message_date
   login        |       7       |    2    | 2014.04.01
   error        |       5       |    2    | 2014.04.01
   login        |       2       |    1    | 2014.04.01
   error        |       1       |    1    | 2014.04.01
   payment      |       1       |    1    | 2014.04.01
```

I cannot figure it out cause I'm silly. Could someone help me please? :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are in luck, because window functions are allowed in the `order by` clause:

```
ORDER BY message_date,
         sum(count (message_subject)) over (partition by message_date, user_id) desc,
         user_id,
         message_count DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Gordon. This query won't work for me and I'm getting the following error from the DB: `ERROR:  column "message_count" does not exist
LINE 26:   sum(message_count),` It seems I cannot do that using PostgreSQL: http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/1632.1128539471@sss.pgh.pa.us

Comment: Ooooop! Okay, I used my brain briefly and was able to get it working. Instead of `sum(message_count)` I did `sum(count(message_subject))` instead and that worked. If you update your answer to have this little detail (or perhaps your own solution) on how to work with an alias column, I will accept your answer!

Comment: @DavidJacob . . . That would be the correct formulation for a `group by` query.